# Can anyone explain how time synchronization relationship between two node clock achieved?

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization

I really don't get how equation 2 is derived from equation 1. The reference [11] says they are in a linear relationship!

Anyone help me to understand it, or what makes any relation non-linear in such example? What would be the relationship if they are non-linear?

[image]

[image]

> Here says that it is a simple data collection algorithm, where from
>   this relationship is derived!

[image]

Comment: Just a thought. Perhaps the assumption here is that the changes due to drift are slow compared to the synchronisation interval, so you can use the actual measured rate drift recorded from a previous synchronisation interval to predict drift across the next (future) synchronisation interval. If the drift has frequency components which vary faster than half the actual synchronisation rate (Nyquist frequency) then aliasing may occur, perhaps adding a jitter error to the future drift prediction.

Comment: Interesting. Yes, the drift is in nano/micro the second level. Both clocks drift rate is similar but not exactly same. The rate is unpredictable changes with the environment such as temperature. So, two clocks are drifting from a common clock (server) in a different rate (though very small in value), they are linearly related? How does the offset which seems a constant value working here? I understand the format is y=mx+c! But if there is no offset or offset is zero, and only time varing drift is in effect, how this going to be looked like? C1(t)=a12.C2(t)?

Comment: If you are measuring time differences at the client node then the offset will cancel out as long as the offset does not change between the local start and finish time measured. The offset is required for measuring the absolute time referenced to some particular past date and time  e.g. number of clock ticks since 12:00:00 midnight January 1 0001. When engineering practical systems the offset (or sum such equivalent) may need to change slightly after each synchronisation event to track a varying drift. Care then needed to prevent errors in the relative time if changes in the offset are large.

Comment: That's right. However, I was just wondering to realize the mathematics of it. It is saying that this is derived from simple data collection algorithm. I have edited my content with a new snap.

Comment: Wouldn't you just describe this as an application of linear extrapolation? The standard derivation is then linear interpolation/extrapolation using the framework of co-ordinate geometry. However the difference here is that both axes in this application are time not distance; the technique is in effect extrapolating forward linearly in time from the last two synchronisation events. I suppose you could use a more sophisticated model/method if you knew from past data how the controlling variables were likely to cycle daily/weekly etc. (e.g. temperature)